# Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError - Target URL is not well-formed

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, watir-webdriver

Selenium Web Driver version: 2.53.4
Firefox version: 46.0.1
Ruby Watir version: 6.0.2
Ruby version: 2.3.1

I was trying to run a cucumber scenario outline that contains 12 examples, strangely the selenium web driver popped up below error randomly after running 1 or 2 examples, and the rest just failed with the same issue.

```
Target URL https://<some_host_name>/portal/login.jsp is not well-formed. (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
[remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20170310-363-1yung1c/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10636:in `FirefoxDriver.prototype.get'
[remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20170310-363-1yung1c/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12661:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h'
[remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20170310-363-1yung1c/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12666:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_'
[remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20170310-363-1yung1c/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12608:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<'some_error_stack_trace'
```

I am pretty sure that the URL is correct, as it's the same for all scenario examples. There is no reason for first 1 or 2 pass but rest fail.

I know it's pretty hard to find a proper version match between FireFox and Selenium Webdriver. The version I chose used to work well but now no longer.

Comment: I haven't found the root cause of the problem. But I was able to resolve it by running `browser.refresh` upon each scenario example completion. So perhaps the FireFox got hung somewhere...

Comment: Can you please include the coding part ?

Comment: Or should you use `browser.close` or `driver.quit`? once each scenario gets done?

Comment: @Gopal I don't know where exactly the problem occurs as the issue is random after running a few scenarios. I guess something goes wrong when the new URL gets injected into the browser, but that is the stand page visit function of selenium.

Comment: @MrityunjeyanS That should work as well. But in my case, the browser is started before any scenario is run and only closed when all tests are finished.

Comment: By what you said, it is not a consistent error, meaning even if the browser is closing, when running back to back scenarios, may be the session has not ended. After every run, the Chromedriver or geckodriver session should have a proper exit. Browser closing end of each scenario may not necessarily end chrome/gecko driver session I guess. Did you try running with `browser.close` or `browser.refresh` after each run using hooks in cucumber

Comment: @MrityunjeyanS yes, I used `browser.refresh` to solve the problem at the end of each scenario (in the `After` hook), as described in my first comment.

Comment: @RuifengMa Cool!